# SQL Server 2008 Subquery with multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 4 tables

Table 1 - DRAWING SUBMISSIONS-DTS

```
SUBMISSION-ID, 
DRAWING-ID,
INWARD-ID,
REVISION NO,
COMMENT DATE,
COMMENTS FORWARDED TO WED,
STATUS OF DRWG,
RECVD AT FFM,
REMARKS,
Last,
Remarks2,
Drawing Sheet,
```

Table 2 - DRAWING-MAIN-DTS

```
DRAWING-ID,
DRAWING CSD NO,
DRAWING TITLE,
ENGINEER INCHARGE,
```

Table 3 - LI PROJECTS

```
PROJECT TITLE,
LI PROJECT NO,
```

Table 4 - Inward

```
INWARD-ID,
REFERENCE NO,
LI PROJECT NO,
TYPE OF INCOMING DOC,
```

All the tables are related with one field in that table.

Reference No in Table 4, Drawing CSD No in Table 2 and LI Project No in Table 3 are Unique.

When a Drawing CSD No will have a new Revision No, a New Reference No is generated. 
Whether the Drawing CSD No is delayed or not is checked on the Last Reference No for that Particular Drawing CSD No.

I want the last Reference No in Table 4, Status of DRWG and Recvd at FFM in Table 1, Engineer inCharge and Drawing Title in Table 2 as the result. We will give only LI Project No as input.

Comment: have you tried writing the query yourself? We're happy to help out, but we're not here to do the whole thing for you. There's far too many freeloaders out there, so we'd like you to show you've at least attempted it yourself.

Comment: Sounds frustrating like homework... but I might try to answer it anyway.

Comment: I have tried. but i was getting full reference Nos. instead of the last. The query i wrote is the following:

Comment: "Select [Inward].[Reference No], [Drawing-Main-DTS].[Drawing CSD No],[Drawing-Main-DTS].[Drawing Title],[Drawing Submissions-DTS].[Revision No],[Drawing Submissions-DTS].[Status of Drwg] from [Inward] inner join [DTSFeedingSystem].dbo.[LI Projects] on [Inward].[LI Project No]=[LI Projects].[LI Project No]  inner join [DTSFeedingSystem].dbo.[Drawing Submissions-DTS] on [Drawing Submissions-DTS].[Inward-ID]=[Inward].[Inward-ID] inner join [DTSFeedingSystem].dbo.[Drawing-Main-DTS] on [Drawing-Main-DTS].[Drawing-ID]=[Drawing Submissions-DTS].[Drawing-ID]

Comment: where [Inward].[Type of Incoming Doc]='" & "DTS" & "' and [LI Projects].[LI Project No]='" & Me.TxtDLIP.Text & "'"

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could've done this using a simple drag & drop "Access-style" UI (though I rarely advise it except for complete beginners). I'm guessing that `[LI PROJECT NO]` is an integer field...

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetLIProjectInfo (@LIProjNo INT)
AS
-- I got this from stackoverflow.com, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559023/sql-server-2008-subquery-with-multiple-tables
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP (1)
      i.[REFERENCE NO],
      ds.[STATUS OF DRWG],
      ds.[RECVD AT FFM],
      dm.[DRAWING TITLE],
      dm.[ENGINEER INCHARGE]
   FROM dbo.[DRAWING SUBMISSIONS-DTS] AS ds
   JOIN dbo.[DRAWING-MAIN-DTS] AS dm
     ON dm.[DRAWING-ID] = ds.[DRAWING-ID]
   JOIN dbo.[Inward] AS i
     ON i.[INWARD-ID] = ds.[INWARD-ID]
   JOIN dbo.[LI PROJECTS] AS p
     ON p.[LI PROJECT NO] = i.[LI PROJECT NO]
   WHERE i.[LI PROJECT NO] = @LIProjNo
   ORDER BY i.[REFERENCE NO] DESC;
END
```

Edit:

For a row per `[DRAWING CSD NO]`, you need to decide whether you want the LIProjNo filter to filter the list of drawings or just the list of projects.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetLIProjectInfo (@LIProjNo INT)
AS
-- I got this from stackoverflow.com, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559023/sql-server-2008-subquery-with-multiple-tables
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT [DRAWING CSD NO]
     FROM dbo.[DRAWING-MAIN-DTS]) AS csd
   OUTER APPLY --Could be CROSS APPLY if you need
   (SELECT TOP (1)
      i.[REFERENCE NO],
      ds.[STATUS OF DRWG],
      ds.[RECVD AT FFM],
      dm.[DRAWING TITLE],
      dm.[ENGINEER INCHARGE]
   FROM dbo.[DRAWING SUBMISSIONS-DTS] AS ds
   JOIN dbo.[DRAWING-MAIN-DTS] AS dm
     ON dm.[DRAWING-ID] = ds.[DRAWING-ID]
   JOIN dbo.[Inward] AS i
     ON i.[INWARD-ID] = ds.[INWARD-ID]
   JOIN dbo.[LI PROJECTS] AS p
     ON p.[LI PROJECT NO] = i.[LI PROJECT NO]
   WHERE i.[LI PROJECT NO] = @LIProjNo
   AND dm.[DRAWING CSD NO] = csd.[DRAWING CSD NO]
   ORDER BY i.[REFERENCE NO] DESC) as inf
   ORDER BY csd.[DRAWING CSD NO];
END
```

Edit:

Because you only need the Drawings that relate to the supplied Project:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetLIProjectInfo (@LIProjNo INT)
AS
-- I got this from stackoverflow.com, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559023/sql-server-2008-subquery-with-multiple-tables
BEGIN
   WITH Numbered AS (
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dm.[DRAWING CSD NO] ORDER BY i.[REFERENCE NO] DESC) AS RowNum,
      i.[REFERENCE NO],
      ds.[STATUS OF DRWG],
      ds.[RECVD AT FFM],
      dm.[DRAWING TITLE],
      dm.[ENGINEER INCHARGE]
   FROM dbo.[DRAWING SUBMISSIONS-DTS] AS ds
   JOIN dbo.[DRAWING-MAIN-DTS] AS dm
     ON dm.[DRAWING-ID] = ds.[DRAWING-ID]
   JOIN dbo.[Inward] AS i
     ON i.[INWARD-ID] = ds.[INWARD-ID]
   JOIN dbo.[LI PROJECTS] AS p
     ON p.[LI PROJECT NO] = i.[LI PROJECT NO]
   WHERE i.[LI PROJECT NO] = @LIProjNo
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM Numbered
   WHERE RowNum = 1;
END
```

Comment: It gave only the last reference no. But I want the last Reference No for each Drawing CSD No.

Comment: I got the result. But it took 3 mts to retrieve the results for one Project No.

Comment: Then you need to put good indexes on your data. Also explain whether you need every drawing or just those related to the Project Number. If the latter, rework the query to use row_number.

Comment: I need for the Drawings related to the Project Number only.